# Spring XD is dying?

Tags: spring, spring-xd

Based on github graphics looks like [Spring XD](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd) is slowly dying.

[image: Github Spring XD graphs]

Is Spring Cloud Data Flow going to replace Spring XD in a near future?

Comment: It already has, as Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Cloud Stream is the successor to Spring XD.

Comment: Just to clarify - it's not dead - it is still supported (bug fixes etc) but it has evolved, with much more flexibility, into the new projects M.Dienum cited.